# Vim not restoring screen contents on Debian?

Tags: vim, debian

I always thought Vim restored the previous contents of the screen upon closing. This allows me to remember what commands I was typing previously and what I wanted to do next.

Recently I've been using Debian 6 and Ubuntu (CLIs only) in a VM for a development project and I've been extremely annoyed with how Vim is operating. After I close the file its contents stay on the screen making me second guess whether I'm still in Vim or not, and having to use history to find out what I typed previously.

I've been unable to find any solution. Using tput smcup and rmcup for instance does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Edit your `.screenrc` file and add the command "`altscreen on`".

Reference from [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Redisplay.html#index-altscreen-123):

```
— Command: altscreen state

    (none)
    If set to on, "alternate screen" support is enabled in virtual 
    terminals, just like in xterm. Initial setting is ‘off’.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the *alternate screen* on your terminal emulator. In `xterm`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Middle Click</kbd> will give you a menu, then select "Enable Alternate Menu Switching".
If that works, you can edit your `.Xresources` to contain: `xterm*titeInhibit: false` and then type `$ xrdb -merge < ~/.Xresource`. I haven't tested that config though.

Comment: No no X, no xterm. :\

Comment: @peuping Sorry I should have realised. It seems that the virtual console doesn't support the alternate screen (I can't find an authoritative link). You could try GNU `screen` or `tmux` terminal multiplexers. For example in a screen session you could try `$ screen vim` which would start your vim session in a new pseudo-terminal and leave your command line untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Under VIM help for **restorescreen**:

```
                        'restorescreen' 'rs' 'norestorescreen' 'nors'
'restorescreen' 'rs'    boolean (default on)
                        global
                        {not in Vi}  {only in Windows 95/NT console version}
        When set, the screen contents is restored when exiting Vim.  This also
        happens when executing external commands.

        For non-Windows Vim: You can set or reset the 't_ti' and 't_te'
        options in your .vimrc.  To disable restoring:
                set t_ti= t_te=
        To enable restoring (for an xterm):
                set t_ti=^[7^[[r^[[?47h t_te=^[[?47l^[8
        (Where ^[ is an <Esc>, type CTRL-V <Esc> to insert it)
```

You may have a

```
set norestorescreen
```

-or-

```
set restorescreen!
```

in your .vimrc somewhere. (or one of your additional scripts).  The default is to restore the previous screen's contents.

Remember to look for the short versions (**nors** / **rs!**) if you don't find the whole option name.